# finding matching files based on content

Tags: bash

I have to write a script that compares two directories and finds duplicate files based on content not filename. I was thinking of using the diff command,  diff -r dir1 dir2, but I get a ton of unwanted information, so my question is, what is the best way to find matching files based on the contents of the file not the name

Answer (score 5):

You could use a hash function like [`md5sum`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum). If the hashes match, the files are identical.

Comment: Hashing is indeed the usual way to do this kind of thing; I'd go with this answer.

Comment: Or maybe use `sha1sum` / `sha256sum`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the -s flag for diff :

```
diff -sqr dir1 dir2 | grep identical
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the `-q` (quiet or brief) option to `diff` useful if you are worried about all the extra information.

Alternatively, you can direct the output of `diff` to `dev/null`.  The important thing is that `diff` has a return code of 0 when the files are the same and 1 if they differ.

```
$ echo "Hello" > x
$ cp x y
$ echo "Goodbye" > z
$ diff -q x y
$ echo $?
0
$ diff -q x z
Files x and z differ
$ echo $?
1
```

To remove the differ message:

```
$ diff -q x z > /dev/null
$ echo $? 
1
```

You should be able to use this in a script easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called `fdupes` which does this kind of search.  On Ubuntu and Debian you can apt-get it.  Installing it probably not harder on other OSes.

If you don't want the external dependency, then like Simon, I suggest you use `md5sum` instead of `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a project (hobby) called "**Duplicate File Finder**" in C++ using OpenSSL library. I am using **md5** as also stated by Simon.

The command for

macOSx is **'$ md5 filename'** and

Linux is **'$ md5sum filename'**.

The project is on [Github](https://github.com/devgeekco/duplicate_file_finder/tree/develop) if you like to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to find if two files are identical is surely `cmp`.

```
cmp file1 file2 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Files are identical"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As `md5sum` is not installed by default on MacOSX.

You can use: `md5 -r` instead.

```
➜ md5 -r /etc/bashrc
7817a5d0c4ebbe0aa5321cf2dd1dcc0b /etc/bashrc

➜ md5sum /etc/bashrc
7817a5d0c4ebbe0aa5321cf2dd1dcc0b  /etc/bashrc
The result is the same.
```

As you can see the result is the same.