# Linux: How do I compare all files in a directory against each other?

Tags: linux, shell

For my homework, I have to check if two files in a directory have the same contents and if so, replace one with a hardlink to the other. My script looks like:

```
    cd $1 # $1 is the directory this script executes in
    FILES=`find . -type f`
    for line1 in $FILES
    do
       for line2 in $FILES
       do
         (check the two files with cmp)
       done
    done
```

My problem is that I can not figure out the conditional expression to make sure that the two files are not the same: If the directory has files a,b,c, and d it should not return true for checking a against a. How do I do this?

Edit: So I've got this:

```
cmp $line1 $line2 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 -a "$line1" != "$line2" ]
```

But it counts the files twice: It checks `a` and `b`, and then `b` and `a`. for some reason, using `<` with strings does not work.

Edit: I think I figured it out, the solution is to use a `\` before the `<`

Comment: Reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286790/finding-matching-files-based-on-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `test`, or its alias `[`:

```
if [ "$line1" < "$line2" ]
then
    check the files
fi
```

Note that I'm using `<` here instead of `!=` (which would otherwise work) so that, once you've compared `a` with `b`, you won't later compare `b` with `a`.

Comment: It's not necessary that the files be named alphabetically, they could be `duskwuff` and `daedalususedperl`, it's just important that their contents be the same. Would `if [cmp "$line1" "$line2"] && [ "$line1 < "$line2" ]` work instead?

Comment: No, because you've used `[` on an expression that isn't a test, and you've got an unpaired double quote. `if [ "$line1" < "$line2" ] && cmp "$line1" "$line2"` would work, though.

Comment: For some reason, using `<` does not work. The closest I've come to is

    cmp $line1 $line2 > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 -a "$line1" != "$line2" ]

Which works correctly but counts the files twice (after comparing `a` and `b`, it compares `b` and `a`)

Comment: Oh wait I should've used a `\` before the `<`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized way to do it that also properly handle files with embedded spaces or similar:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
compare() {
  first=$1
  shift
  for i do
    cmp -s "$first" "$i" || printf " %s and %s differ\n" "$first" "$i"
  done
}
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
  compare "$@"
  shift
done ' sh {} +
```